# <idea-version> in plugin.xml in overwritten in final jar

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I am creating a custom plugin and using  details in plugin.xml file:

```
<idea-version since-build="162.0" until-build="181.*"/>
```

But after I build the plugin project using gradle-build task , i am seeing the plugin.xml in final jar has below  . Somehow the tag I have defined is getting overwritten.

```
<idea-version since-build="181.4445" until-build="181.*"/>
```

I want to use "162.0" to make plugin work in older IDE versions.

Comment: Replied at https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000178660--idea-version-is-getting-overwritten-in-jar.

Comment: Thanks after adding this in build.gradle, it worked`patchPluginXml {
    sinceBuild '162.*'
}`

Answer (score 6):

You can configure Gradle to patch `plugin.xml` file as [described in the documentation](https://github.com/JetBrains/gradle-intellij-plugin#patching-dsl):

```
patchPluginXml {
  sinceBuild '162'
  untilBuild '181'
}
```

Comment: Thanks saved me tonnes of time. I was trying to change the intellij { version} and it kept patching the plugin.xml